# How can I insert a GitHub emoji in a code section of a Markdown file?

Tags: github, markdown, emoji

I am making a documentation project on GitHub, so I have edited all the contents in my Markdown file, but I am facing an issue. I don't know how to insert GitHub emojis in the code section of the Markdown file.

```
POST /api/yo HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: :large_blue_circle:
email=joe@example.com&message=Yo
```

`:large_blue_circle:` is .

[image: The target of this question]

Comment: Including emoji in your content is one thing, but why are you trying to use `:large_blue_circle:` as your _`Content-Type`?_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the emoji character itself in the code block, like this:

```
POST /api/yo HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: 
email=joe@example.com&message=Yo
```